# How to delete particular tag from a parent node?

Tags: javascript

The code

```
<div class="something>
    <input type="text onchange="some_function(this)">
    <span>Blqh blqh</span>
    <span>Blq blq</span>
</div>
```

Once there is a change in the input I want `some_function(this)` to delete all `<span>` tags. So far in the function I have:

```
function some_function(x_this) {
   var parent=x_this.parentNode;
}
```

How do i get all the `<span>` elements and delete them?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
function some_function(x_this) {
   var parent=x_this.parentNode,
       spans = parent.getElementsByTagName('span');

   for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
      parent.removeChild(spans[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: `removeChild` doesn't accept a string, I don't know why this is upvoted.

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop to iterate over a collection. Use a normal `for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {`

Comment: @Ian, please explain why? interestingly :)

Comment: This won't work if the `<span>` is not a child. Also, `spans` will be a **live** _NodeList_, so you can't loop like this, again.

Comment: @maximkou Iterating with `for in` iterates over the object's enumerable properties, which can sometimes be more than you want/expect. Also, when you start removing things from the collection, it might mess up because `for in` doesn't iterate in a certain order, while a normal `for` does (since you specify that order)

Comment: @Ian, thanks.I know about it, but I have never experienced this when iterating node lists.

Comment: @maximkou please observe this failing testcase http://jsfiddle.net/qZxJu/ and possibly consider this failing testcase http://jsfiddle.net/qZxJu/1/

Answer (score 2):

With the following *HTML*, for example

```
<div id="foo">
    <input />
    <span>Blqh blqh</span>
    <span>Blq blq</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

you could run this *JavaScript*

```
var parent = document.getElementById('foo'), i = parent.childNodes.length;
while (i--) 
    if (parent.childNodes[i].tagName === 'SPAN')
        parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[i]);
```

Comment: Might as well use `children` instead of `childNodes`, otherwise you're looping over unnecessary nodes (possibly)

Comment: @Ian would `children` work on a non-HTML document, too? As I have it, the **loop** should work on any document type.

Comment: I suppose it would not work outside of an HTML document, but I didn't realize we were trying to support that. If the OP was talking about non-HTML, maybe that would be relevant. Anyways, why are you using `tagName` then? Your code wouldn't work in an XML document, because `tagName` preserves the case, so it would be "span", not "SPAN". `nodeName` should always be used for getting the "tag name", it's more consistent

Comment: @Ian Ah, true. Evidently I was trying to outsmart myself.. at least it wouldn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent').find('span').remove();
```

or use pure js

```
var childrenspan = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var i=0;i<childrenspan.length;i++)
{
   childrenspan[i].parentNode.removeChild(childrenspan[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **jquery** then add id to your Div tag and then

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <input />
    <span>Blqh blqh</span>
    <span>Blq blq</span>
    <br />
</div>
```

Use this jquery code:

```
$('#mydiv').find('span').remove()
```

Comment: I tried this in the environment suggested by _OP's_ tags and got `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`